# ksh split string to array to write to file

Tags: unix, ksh

Here is the code i use to select a string from database. Split and then write to a text file .

```
#Get information from DB for the given entrynum
RETVAL=`sqlplus -s username/pwd@db <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
SELECT  (entrynum|| '-'||path||'-'|| syear||'-'|| eyear||'-'|| type) as RET
    FROM  entrydetails WHERE entrynum = 123;

EXIT;
EOF`    

print "$scriptname return value :$RETVAL " 1>&2
#Output :123-/userx/data/tt-2015-2015-1

#split each value into an array
arr=$(echo $RETVAL | tr "-" "\n")

#write to text variable
writeText="export entrynum=${arr[0]}\n
          export path=${arr[1]}\n
          export Syear=${arr[2]}\n
          export eyear=${arr[3]}\n
          export type=${arr[4]}";

#write text to file
echo $writeText > ../in/log_file
```

The output i get in the file is

```
export entrynum=123 /userx/data/1 2015 2015 1
 export path=
 export syesr=
 export eyear=
 export type=
```

Expected result is

```
export entrynum=123   
export path=/userx/data/1
export syesr=2015
export eyear=2015 
export type=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more pair of parens around the array assignment

`arr=($(echo $RETVAL | tr "-" "\n"))`

the `$()` is an eval.  `arr=()` is a compound assignment. Split is on whitespace, so you could just even use a space rather than a newline to tr like this

`tr "-" " "`

if your ksh doesn't support compound assignment you could use `set -A`

`set -A arr -- $(echo $RETVAL | tr "-" " ")`

Comment: it works for me -- ksh 
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01 - alternative is to use an explicit set - I updated the answer to illustrate this

Comment: tried this to check the verion [ "`echo "\c" | grep c`" ] && echo ksh93 || echo ksh88. It is ksh88.  Still i get the same error

Comment: yes, you need 93 for the =(). I updated the answer to offer an alternative